# Given a function $F$, how to evaluate $\max_{t\in (0,1)}\left\vert \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}(ty)\right\vert$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

As an "extra problem" for my calculus 2 test class we got the following. Since it is an extra problem, I expected it to be more difficult than the other exercises, but actually but not that much. This is the problem:

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$F:(x_1, x_2, x_3)\mapsto -\frac{1}{|x|^2} +\frac{1}{|x|}\in\mathbb{R}.$$
For a fixed $y\in\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{0\}$, find
$$\max_{t\in (0,1)}\left\vert \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}(ty)\right\vert.$$

To start I computed $\nabla F(x)$ which is
$$\nabla F(x) = \left(\frac{2}{|x|^4}-\frac{1}{|x|^3}\right) x,$$
where $x$ denotes the vector $x=(x_1, x_2, x_3)$.

I went ahead by computing the second partial derivatives. I had
$$\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x_i^2} = \frac{2}{|x|^4}-\frac{1}{|x|^3} +\frac{3x_i^2}{|x|^5}-\frac{8x_i^2}{|x|^6}, \quad i\in\{1, 2, 3\}$$
and
$$\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x_i\partial x_j} = \frac{3x_i x_j}{|x|^5}-\frac{8x_i x_j}{|x|^6}, \quad i\in\{1, 2, 3\}, i\neq j.$$

I got stuck at this point since I have no idea how to establish the maximum. I’ve been thinking about it unsuccessfully for a couple of days, but I am really interested in the solution.

Could someone please help in finding that maximum? Any hint will be very helpful.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Supposing the computations are correct (I didn't check them myself) then for a fixed $y\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ you can completely forget about $y$ and just play around with $h(t) = \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}(ty) = \frac{x_i x_j}{t^3|x|^5}\left(3 - \frac{8/|x|}{t}\right) = \frac{\alpha}{t^3}\left(3 - \frac{\beta}{t}\right)$, $t\in(0, 1)$.

Perhaps you will need to check some cases, but maybe this can lead you to something.

Comment: @Yuumita, could you please provide more details about that? It seems to me that there are too many unknowns. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I've made the mistake of fixing $y$ but then using $x$, so instead suppose that we fix $x\neq 0$. Now $x_k$ are all known ($x$ is fixed, it's not a variable), so using the function I mentioned we have $\alpha = \frac{x_i x_j}{|x|^5}\neq 0$ and $\beta = \frac{8}{|x|} > 0$ and both can be though of as known values. You want to find the local maxs/mins of $h$ in $(0, 1)$ and see if they are global max/mins. Also notice that since you're searching for $\max_{t\in(0,1)}|h(t)|$ where $t$ is in an open interval, the max will be achieved in a local max of $|h|$, which will be a local min/max of $h$.

Comment: @Yuumita I am trying to draw that function with varying $\alpha$ and $\beta$. No success so far.

Comment: No drawings are necessary for solving the problem. If you really want to draw something, even if really abstract, you must take some cases. For example $\alpha<0$ is a different case from $\alpha>0$ and possibly $\beta<\frac{9}{4}$ different from $\beta \geq \frac{9}{4}$. Unfortunately with this approach there is casework, namely for some vectors $x\in R^3\setminus\{0\}$ there isn't a maximum (there will be a supremum but I don't think your professor asks that).

Comment: I was writing a solution with my approach (analysing the function $h$, which ends up being very simple in fact) until I realised there might be something up with the excersise. What can you say about the limit to $0^+$ of the value you want to maximize? Considering my definition of $h$ I think it's pretty easy to find that it goes to $+\infty$ (depending on the sign of $-\alpha \beta = -\frac{8x_i x_j}{|x|^6}$, $h$ goes to $\pm \infty$).
Perhaps you are asked to find the minimum of the expression?

Comment: @Yuumita, could you please provide more details as an answer? I think I am missing something.

Comment: Also, how come you’re not considering $\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x_i^2}$?

Comment: @Bishop For a fixed $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$($x\neq0$) let $h(t) = h_x(t) =\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}(tx) = \frac{3(tx_i)(tx_j)}{|tx|^5} - \frac{8(tx_i)(tx_j)}{|tx|^6} = \frac{x_ix_j}{|x|^5}\left(\frac{3}{t^3}-\frac{8/|x|}{t^4}\right)$.
We can write $h(t) = \alpha\left(\frac{3}{t^3} - \frac{\beta}{t^4}\right)$ for some known $\alpha, \beta$
Now the limit of $h$ as $t$ approaches $0^+$ ends up $\pm \infty$. I can post my analysis of $h$ as an answer but it doesn't help with the problem that arises from the infinity.

Comment: Avoid display-style formulas in subject lines; it messes up displays when listing questions.

Comment: That's a determinant, right? So you don't want to find extrema of the individual matrix elements.

Comment: I get some nasty computations in the result for maximum of the Hessian determinant. The test author might have thought the problem is easier than it actually is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the family of functions

$$G_{ij}(t;y):=\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(ty)$$

Write
$$F(x)=f(|x|) \\ f(s)=-\frac{1}{s^2}+\frac{1}{s}$$
Using the chain rule,
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_i}(x)=f'(|x|)~\frac{x_i}{|x|}$$

And the product rule, $$ \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(x)=f''(|x|)\frac{x_ix_j}{|x|^2}+f'(|x|)\frac{\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_j}|x|-\frac{x_j}{|x|}x_i}{|x|^2} \\ =f''(|x|)\frac{x_ix_j}{|x|^2}-f'(|x|)\frac{x_ix_j}{|x|^3}+\delta_{ij}f'(|x|)\frac{1}{|x|}$$

Now, compute
$$f'(s)=\frac{2}{s^3}-\frac{1}{s^2} \\ f''(s)=\frac{-6}{s^4}+\frac{2}{s^3}$$

Hence
$$\frac{\partial ^2 F}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(x)=\frac{x_ix_j}{|x|^2}\left(f''(|x|)-\frac{f'(|x|)}{x}+\delta_{ij}f'(|x|)\frac{1}{|x|}\right) \\ 
=\frac{x_ix_j}{|x|^2}\left(\frac{-6}{|x|^4}+\frac{2}{|x|^3}-\frac{2}{|x|^4}+\frac{1}{|x|^3}+\delta_{ij}\left(\frac{2}{|x|^4}-\frac{1}{|x|^3}\right)\right) \\ =\frac{x_ix_j}{|x|^5}\left(3-\frac{8}{|x|}+\delta_{ij}\left(\frac{2}{|x|}-1\right)\right) \\ 
=\frac{x_ix_j}{|x|^5}\left((3-\delta_{ij})+\frac{2}{|x|}\left(\delta_{ij}-4\right)\right)$$

Therefore
$$G_{ij}(t;y)=\frac{ty_ity_j}{|ty|^5}\left((3-\delta_{ij})+\frac{2}{|ty|}\left(\delta_{ij}-4\right)\right) \\ =|t|^{-3}\frac{y_iy_j}{|y|}\left((3-\delta_{ij})+t^{-1}\frac{2}{|y|}\left(\delta_{ij}-4\right)\right)$$

So for $i\neq j$ and $t\in(0,1)$,
$$|G_{ij}(t;y)|=b~t^{-3}|3-8at^{-1}|$$
Where $a=|y_iy_j/|y|^5|$ and $a=1/|y|$. This clearly is unbounded.

On the other hand for $i=j$,
$$|G_{ii}(t;y)|=bt^{-3}|2-6at^{-1}|$$

Same thing.

Comment: thank you for the answer. Why did you not consider the derivatives $\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x_i^2}$, too?

Comment: But a matrix with large elements can still have a small determinant.

Comment: @C.Bishop Just set $i=j$.

Comment: @aschepler Where are you getting this "determinant" idea from?

Comment: @K.defaoite, I am not sure that it is enough to set $i=j$. It seems to me that, if $i=j$, the derivative is the one I wrote in my question (which is a bit different).

Comment: @C.Bishop Yes, you are right, I forgot the term $\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_j}$. Will update.

Comment: @C.Bishop It doesn't change anything.

Comment: @K.defaoite thank you for editing your answer.

Comment: Since $i$ and $j$ don't appear in the subscript of $\max$, I take $$\max_{t \in (0,1)} \left|\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x_i\, \partial x_j}(ty)\right|$$ to mean the maximum with respect to $t$ of the Hessian determinant. Still, I think the determinant does also turn out to be unbounded as $t \to 0^+$.

Comment: Except hmm, I think the limit as $t \to 0^+$ is $-\infty$, not $+\infty$. So there could still be an actual answer.

Comment: I have the same understanding as @aschepler. 
For me the objective function is the determinant of 
$\mathbf{H}_F(t\mathbf{y})
$ with the Hessian matrix 
$
\mathbf{H}_F(\mathbf{x})
=
\left( 2 a^{-4}-a^{-3} \right) \mathbf{I}_3+
\left( 3 a^{-5}-8 a^{-6} \right) \mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T
$
and
$a=\|\mathbf{x}\|$.
The use of the matrix determinant lemma [wiki][1] can simplify this expression but the maximum remains challenging.


  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma

Comment: @Steph For what it's worth, I got $|H_F(ty)| = 2(t|y|-3)(t|y|-2)^2 t^{-12}|y|^{-14}$. It has one local maximum if $|y|$ is small enough, but the expression Wolfram Alpha gives is a horrible mess.

Comment: Yes very strange. If i put $b=1/\| \mathbf{x} \|$, I obtain as a determinant $-24\ b^9 (b-2)^2 (b-3)$ and after inserting $t$, I obtain $\frac{-24}{(ty)^{12}} \left(1-2ty \right)^2 
\left(1-3ty \right)$ which is different from yours. Anyway, I think something went wrong somewhere. Would be interesting to have the final word from the teacher.